# PHP/MySQL/HTML Add user Error?

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have file siswa-tambah.php

```
    <?php
//siswa-tambah.php
//periksa apakah username = kosong dan hak akses = adm
if(empty($_SESSION['username']) OR ($_SESSION['akses']<>'adm')){
    //jika user belum login
    echo "Anda harus login untuk dapat mengakses halaman ini !\n";
    echo "<a href=index.php>Kembali</a>";
} else {
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        //proses simpan
        $nis=$_POST['nis'];
        $nama=$_POST['nama'];
        $tgl_lahir=$_POST['thn'].'-'.$_POST['bln'].'-'.$_POST['tgl'];
        $sex=$_POST['sex'];
        $pass=$_POST['pass'];
        $uploaddir = 'foto/';
        $foto = basename($_FILES['foto']['name']);

        //sql simpan, password menggunakan nomor induk
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO siswa VALUES('$nis','$nama','$tgl_lahir','$sex','$pass','$foto')");
        if($sql){
            echo "Data berhasil disimpan!";
        } else {
            echo "Ada ERROR!";
        }
    } else {
?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="">
<table border="0">
<tr>
<td>NIS/USERNAME</td>
<td><input type="text" size="10" name="nis"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Nama Lengkap</td>
<td><input type="text" size="25" name="nama"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Tanggal Lahir</td>
<td>
<?php
    echo '<select name="tgl">';
    for($tgl=1; $tgl<=31; $tgl++){
        echo '<option value="'.$tgl.'">'.$tgl.'</option>';
}
        echo '</select>'; 

    echo '<select name="bln">';
    $arrBulan = array(1=>'Januari','Pebruari','Maret','April','Mei','Juni','Juli','Agustus','September','Oktober','Nopember','Desember');
    foreach($arrBulan as $b => $bln){
        echo '<option value="'.$b.'">'.$bln.'</option>';
    }
        echo '</select>';

        echo '<select name="thn">';
    foreach(range(date('Y'), 1930) as $thn){
        echo '<option value="'.$thn.'">'.$thn.'</option>';
    }
        echo '</select>';
?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Jenis Kelamin</td>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="L">Laki-Laki 
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="P">Perempuan
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>
<input type="password" name="pass">
<input type="hidden" name="nis" value="<?php echo $hsl['nis']; ?>">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Foto</td>
<td><input type="file" name="foto"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Simpan"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

heres my problem when i click Submit button, nis is wrong but others correct , where i can fix this, "nis" when i insert/add "br /> b>Noti" , i'm so confuse please correct my code

Please help, thanks

Comment: [Screenshot](http://oi39.tinypic.com/2r7324z.jpg) "nis" is wrong

Comment: There's a PHP error in there. You need to figure out what it is as that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have two form objects with the name 'nis':

```
<td>NIS/USERNAME</td>
<td><input type="text" size="10" name="nis"></td>
```

and

```
<input type="hidden" name="nis" value="<?php echo $hsl['nis']; ?>">
```

Comment: oh yes, you're right now my code work, thank you :) so much Thomas